# Kubernetes: How can i send email when pesistent volume are 80% full?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, rancher, persistent-volumes

I have databases delpoyed as StatefullSet on my kubernetes cluster, i would like to know how can i make alerts (send email) when Persistent Volumes are 80% full?

P.S: This k8s cluster is deployed using Rancher v2.4

Answer (score 1):

You will need to monitor your volumes from Prometheus, the link above from Manoj is a good start or visit [kubepersistentvolumefillingup](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubepersistentvolumefillingup)

After prometheus is happy, you can configure alert manager to generate email alerts.

Good luck.

There is a helm chart to get you started.  [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus)

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked at Kubernetes mixin alerts `KubePersistentVolumeFillingUp` in https://monitoring.mixins.dev/kubernetes ?